# Copy File task failed with the error of Unhandled: Not found SourceFolder

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, build-pipeline

I am very new CI/CD domain of Aure Dev Ops. So I Created a test ASP.NET MVC application. I checkedin the application in git repo at visual studio online.
My build pipeline is working fine, but the `ms build` configuration of where my published files will be, seems to be not found.
here is my `msbuild configuration` in my `yml` file:

```
msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
```

And in my release pipeline, I am using a `copy task` with the following `yml`

```
steps:
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/deploy'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/deploy'
```

and this is the error I get when I try to deploy the release:

```
 ##[error]Unhandled: Not found SourceFolder: D:\a\r1\a\$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory` doesn't exist in a release pipeline. You need to use a [Publish Build Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) task in your build pipeline, then download the artifacts using the [Download Build Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) task in your release pipeline.